# Which Data structure used in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ropes

I know that Notepad++ used Gap Buffer, and XI editor used Rope.
But I don't know which data structure behind the Visual Studio Code.

Do you know which data structure used in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 2):

Based on [an article on the Visual Studio website about how the text buffer was implemented for Visual Studio Code 1.21](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2018/03/23/text-buffer-reimplementation), the text buffer is apparently represented by a [piece table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piece_table) - a data structure that stores the initial text in one node, and then subsequent edits in other nodes.

They then improved its performance by:

- caching the starts of lines, to make it easier to jump around the text buffer
- making sure the initial text didn't get too big for their Javascript engine (V8) to handle, by storing the initial text as a list of buffers
- reworking that cache of starts of lines to use a red-black tree for even better performance

to get what the author calls a "Multiple buffer piece table with red-black tree, optimized for line model" and then immediately shortens to "piece tree".